# Remove DOM element explicitly to avoid memory leakage in javascript

Tags: javascript, garbage-collection, cross-browser

I was checking the [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management#garbage_collection) in MDN about garbage collection. When I come across the 'Real-life example' section, the term 'explicitly removed' in below statement confused me.

> If the property is not **explicitly removed** or nulled, a reference-counting garbage collector will always have at least one reference intact and will keep the DOM element in memory even if it was removed from the DOM tree

Can `document.removeChild` fulfill the criteria of removing DOM element explicitly?

Comment: @StackSlave Just curious. I have browsed S.O looking for answers. Some of those saying that only **refreshing the page** can remove the DOM element completely. Don't know whether it is true or not.

Comment: It's explained perfectly on the doc link you provided. An Element is an Object. If you `Element.removeChlid(child)` that will just remove a child from that Element in the DOM. If `child` is in reference to an Element like `const child = document.createElement('div')` you could re-append `child` to the DOM, because garbage collection hasn't happened. If you did like `child = null;` then there is no need for the Element under that reference and it can be garbage collected. Good to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can `document.removeChild` fulfill the criteria of removing DOM element explicitly?

The question indicates some confusion: there is no criteria to explicitly remove the DOM node. Removing an element from the DOM, either explicitly or implicitly (by removing an ancestral element from it descends), should make it available for memory collection assuming no reference to the removed element is retained in code. The *property* mentioned at the beginning of the quoted article refers to the `div.circularReference` property used in the example, whose value was set to `div` to create a circular reference back from the property to the element.

Explicitly removing "the property" could be achieved by deleting or changing the property's value, for example with

```
 div.circularReference = null; // or
 delete div.circularReference;
```

Removing the circular reference could be done before or after removal of `div` from the DOM. The good news is where the article says reference-counting garbage collector are no longer used in modern browsers.